# Calculate Columns Cumulative Sum and Percentage in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I need some help with creating a query as SAS proc SQL.

Consider the following dataset which has sales from different regions already bucketed by 3 hour chunks (its only a subset, actual data covers 24 hours):

```
 Date        ObsAtHour Region   Sales
 1/1/2018    2         Asia     76 
 1/1/2018    2         Africa   5 
 1/1/2018    5         Asia     14
 1/1/2018    5         Africa   10
 2/1/2018    2         Asia     40
 2/1/2018    2         Africa   1 
 2/1/2018    5         Asia     15
 2/1/2018    5         Africa   20
```

I get data covering last 45 days..

I am trying to do two things

1)  Group by date, ObsAtHour and Region and get cumulative sum of Sales such that I get something like

```
 Date        ObsAtHour Region   Sales CumSales
 1/1/2018    2         Asia     76    76
 1/1/2018    2         Africa   5     5
 1/1/2018    5         Asia     14    90
 1/1/2018    5         Africa   10    15
 2/1/2018    2         Asia     40    40
 2/1/2018    2         Africa   1     1
 2/1/2018    5         Asia     15    55
 2/1/2018    5         Africa   20    21
```

2) Get Percentage for sales that indicate what percentage of daily sales per Region has been achieved at any obsAtHour. It would look like:

```
 Date        ObsAtHour Region   Sales CumSales  Pct
 1/1/2018    2         Asia     76    76        84%
 1/1/2018    2         Africa   5     5         33%
 1/1/2018    5         Asia     14    90        100%
 1/1/2018    5         Africa   10    15        100%
 2/1/2018    2         Asia     40    40        72% 
 2/1/2018    2         Africa   1     1         4.76%
 2/1/2018    5         Asia     15    55        100%
 2/1/2018    5         Africa   20    21        100%
```

Your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like below

```
data have;
input Date:mmddyy10.        ObsAtHour Region $  Sales;
format date mmddyy10;
datalines;
1/1/2018    2         Asia     76 
1/1/2018    2         Africa   5 
1/1/2018    5         Asia     14
1/1/2018    5         Africa   10
2/1/2018    2         Asia     40
2/1/2018    2         Africa   1 
2/1/2018    5         Asia     15
2/1/2018    5         Africa   20
 ;
 proc sort data=have;
 by date region;
 run;

/* this gives moving sum*/
 data have1;
format date mmddyy10.;
set have;
by   date region;
 if first.region then sumsales = sales;
  else sumsales+sales;
  run;

/* get the total sales from your intial table by group and join it back 
and calculate the percent*/
proc sql;
select a.*, sumsales/tot_sales  as per format =percent10.2 from 
(select * from have1)a
inner join
(select region , date, sum(sales) as tot_sales
from have
group by 1, 2)b
on a.region =b.region
 and a.date =b.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding the following query is that the cumulative levels will be called tiers.  The tiers are used as part of the self-join criteria to restrict the items that are grouped for being summed.

**Data**

```
data have;
input Date ddmmyy10. ObsAtHour Region $  Sales;
format Date yymmdd10.;
datalines;
 1/1/2018    2         Asia     76 
 1/1/2018    2         Africa   5 
 1/1/2018    5         Asia     14
 1/1/2018    5         Africa   10
 2/1/2018    2         Asia     40
 2/1/2018    2         Africa   1 
 2/1/2018    5         Asia     15
 2/1/2018    5         Africa   20
run;
```

**Sample query**

The second query (percentage computation) is performed off the result of the first query (cumulative computation), however, the first query could by embedded as a nested query within the second one.

```
proc sql;
  create table want(label='Cumulative within day up to obsathour') as
  select 
    tiers.Date
  , tiers.ObsAtHour
  , tiers.Region
  , Sum(case when have.ObsAtHour = tiers.ObsAtHour then have.Sales else 0 end) as SalesAtTier
  , Sum(have.Sales) as CumSales
  , Count(*) as CumCount
  from
    have
  join
    (select distinct Date, ObsAtHour, Region from have) as tiers
  on
    have.Date = tiers.Date
    and have.Region = tiers.Region
    and have.ObsAtHour <= tiers.ObsAtHour
  group by
    tiers.Date, tiers.Region, tiers.ObsAtHour
  order 
    by Date, ObsAtHour, Region
  ;

  create table want2 as
  select
    cum.Date
  , cum.ObsAtHour
  , cum.Region
  , cum.SalesAtTier
  , cum.CumSales
  , cum.CumSales / Sum(cum.SalesAtTier) as fraction format=Percent7.2
  from
    want as cum
  group by
    cum.Date, cum.Region
  order by 
    cum.Date, cum.ObsAtHour, cum.Region
  ;
```